# c# TreeView node path

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I have a treeview with multiple nodes with the same text and quite nested inside.

I wonder how to select node and get exact path of it by index not text

Like selected is

`treeview.nodes[3].nodes[2].nodes[7]`

the path is 3/2/7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample how it should work to get a `string` path from your `Treeview`.

```
TreeNode tmp = treeview.nodes[3].nodes[2].nodes[7];
string path = String.Empty;

while(tmp != null)
{
   path.insert(0, "/" tmp.Index);
   tmp = tmp.Parent;
}
path.Remove(0,1); // remove first '/' sign
```

Not fully tested this sample, but I should be hint for you. Hope that will solve your problem, if not please add further details to your question.